# Android SocketTimeoutException on WiFi using Retrofit / OkHttpClient

Tags: android, timeout, wifi, retrofit, okhttp

I know similar questions have been asked but this one is slightly different.

We have an app that does some HTTP connectivity with our server.

While running the app on an **LG Nexus 5X** or **Sumsung Galaxy 5**, using any of our 3 **WiFi** routers, the connection **times out** ("SocketTimeoutException: timeout" due to "SocketException: Socket closed"). 
The connection **doesn't timeout** if we use **cellular** network, **tethering** between devices or the **simulator** on a laptop connected to the same  (problematic) WiFi routers.

Just to point out, the routers are connected to different ISPs.

Did anyone ever experience anything like it or have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: maybe your wifi router blocks the phones' mac addresses

Comment: Check if you are using the correct baseurl? hit the same API in browser or postman and check if it is working?

Comment: Did check the url from Chrome on the LG and it works. The app does connect to a server running locally (on the same network).

Comment: May be some routers have restrictions to access the URL can you check security settings of your routers.

Comment: We can access the urls from Chrome on these devices or from the simulator on a laptop, using these routers. The issue seems to be between the routers and the app (Retrofit, OkHttp ?) on these devices.

Comment: Maybe the wifi connection is not strong enough and ends up dying when a keepalive packet fails to be acknowledged. Did you try with a local server ?

Comment: Solved, see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Trying a GET instead of a POST (with a JSON body of ~4K bytes) seemed to work fine. So, after a session with *tcpdump*, server side, it turned out that the request **does reach** the server but it's "**corrupted**". The first ~300 bytes and the last ~1000 bytes do reach the server but the middle ~2500 **bytes** are **missing** (could be due to some service provider infrastructure/ shaper or whatever).

In any case, lowering the buffer size of the *OKHttpClient* instance (providing it with a new *SocketFactory*) to 512, did the trick.

Thanks to all of those who tried to assist.